# For cube building do we need to use Cognos Transformer or Cube Designer?

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi, cubes

For Cognos cube building I heard about using Cognos Transformer?. But now I see there is an another tool called Cube Designer?. Which one do we need to use for normal cube building?. Is it Cognos Cube Designer latest and succeeded the other one ?.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.  “Different data requirements require different data solutions. “

Cognos has a decision guide table outlining the fundamental aspects of the various technologies.   I've found a couple of links for it.

But Transformer is the modeler for PowerCubes and Cube Designer is the modeler for Cognos Dynamic cubes.  Your business requirements would drive the technology that you adopt and that, in turn, would dictate the modeling tool that you would be using.

https://books.google.ca/books?id=Re5JCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA10&lpg=PA10&dq=use+cases+for+dynamic+cubes&source=bl&ots=5AwNTaTX7p&sig=2z-mDsJK6g_l_HNxE6P3jD8FTpc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwicpa_vyO7VAhXs34MKHco4BP8Q6AEIWzAJ#v=onepage&q=use%20cases%20for%20dynamic%20cubes&f=false

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27036155

Answer (score 0):

Both tools and Cubes are supported. PowerCubes build by transformer have been used for a long time (more than 25 years) and will suite for less than 1 billion rows, small number of dimensions. Performance often relys on filesystem performance. Dynamic cubes are using a hybrid approach: building aggregates for OLAP ad hoc from datasource, by using aggregate tables inside database or using In Memory aggregates (often the fastest method). IBM tells us that Dynamic Cubes are made for big data. But this does often not work because of limitations like 2 billion tuples, etc. In most cases dynamic cubes will work fine, fast and are easy to maintain and develop.